# labelSeparator in extjs , need combobox in other line

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I want the combobox in the next line the fieldLabel.

Although i tried labelSeparator: '\n'. but it didnt work. 
 Please help

```
xtype:'combo',
fieldLabel:'XYZ',
store:['A', 'B', 'C'],
autoSelect:true,
labelSeparator: '\n',
forceSelection:true
```

Comment: See docs about `labelAlign`

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Evan in his comment, use labelAlign to arrange the fieldLabel.

```
xtype:'combo',
fieldLabel:'XYZ',
store:['A', 'B', 'C'],
autoSelect:true,
labelAlign:'top',
forceSelection:true
```